# Different Values for Registry Keys in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'm trying to build a Windows 7 image, I get all the building process.

I was defining a list of all the usable software to be started when the PC boots up. I mainly used tow tools: Windows Registry and CCleaner. In the Registry I see some programs but when I check CCleaner I see other, not shown in the Registry. When I click to see the values shown in CCleaner in the Registry, there seem to be *two versions* of the same Registry locations.

Check the example image

[image: .]

I don't really understand what is happening, I must say this is in the Audit Mode and with Windows 7 up to date. Hope you can help me in this.

Comment: CCleaner Free edition is limited to ONE user account, while the Pro edition gives you access to all users accounts. So, in the Free edition you'll be able to view HKEY_Current_USER keys ONLY, while in Pro edition you'll be able to get the HKEY_Current_USER & HKEY_Local_Machine access. So, I am wondering if this is the cause of what you're experiencing. Check the Run under HKEY_Current_USER, and see if is it the same as CCleaner Startup list.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @iSR5. In HKCU, the Run location contains different values than HKLM (as spected), only the startup of CCleaner is shown. What I mean is: I opened two instances of the Registry one directly using the regedit command and the other one from CCleaner, both of them have completely different values but they are placed in the same registry location. That's why I'm confused, but in the Startup list that appears in CCleaner, all the startup programs are shown from the "two versions" of the Registry locations.

Comment: If they have to same keys, then you shouldn't be worry, and mainly is just because of the CCleaner as I stated before (it might be a CCleaner bug tho).